# swift protocol delegate always return nil

Tags: ios, swift

I have this protocol delegate defined in my View Controller:

```
protocol PickerDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    func updateMessage(meesage: String)
}
```

and then I called this in my View Controller:

```
class GradingController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, SDataGridDataSourceHelperDelegate, SLAIssuedFinalGradingDelegate, CityApprovalIssuedDelegate, CityCommentReceivedDelegate, DepositReceivedDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    var pickerDelegate: PickerDelegate?

}
```

And then I am calling my method inside the protocol delegate (this is where its nil):

```
func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {

    let controller = popoverPresentationController.presentedViewController as! CommentsController
    pickerDelegate?.updateMessage(meesage: controller.commentView.text)

}
```

And I am using this delegate in my custom class:

```
class TextCell: SDataGridCell, PickerDelegate {

    var dataGrid: ShinobiDataGrid?

    private var _commentText = ""

    private var label: UILabel?

    var commentText: String {

        get {
            return _commentText
        }

        set(commentText) {

            if(commentText != "")
            {
                label?.text = commentText
            }
            else
            {
                label?.text = "N/A"
            }
        }

    }

    override init(reuseIdentifier identifier: String!) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: identifier)

        label = UILabel()

        label?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)

        label?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 32)

        addSubview(label!)

        let pickerViewController = GradingController()
        pickerViewController.pickerDelegate = self

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override func respondToEditEvent() {

        if dataGrid?.delegate.responds(to: #selector(SDataGridDelegate.shinobiDataGrid(_:shouldBeginEditingCellAtCoordinate:))) ?? false {
            if dataGrid?.delegate.shinobiDataGrid!(dataGrid, shouldBeginEditingCellAtCoordinate: coordinate) == false {
                return
            }
        }

        if dataGrid?.delegate.responds(to: #selector(SDataGridDelegate.shinobiDataGrid(_:willBeginEditingCellAtCoordinate:))) ?? false {
            dataGrid?.delegate.shinobiDataGrid!(dataGrid, willBeginEditingCellAtCoordinate: coordinate)
        }

    }

    func updateMessage(meesage: String) {
        commentText = meesage
    }
}
```

But the updateMessage method is not being called, my delegate is nil in my View Controller when I try to use it in popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover but it always return nil :(

What am I doing wrong?

This is the TextCell in GradingController:

```
func dataGridDataSourceHelper(_ helper: SDataGridDataSourceHelper!, populateCell cell: SDataGridCell!, withValue value: Any!, forProperty propertyKey: String!, sourceObject object: Any!) -> Bool {

        let cellDataObj = object as? GradingData

        if(propertyKey == "GradingRepair")
        {

            let textCell = cell as? TextCell

            textCell?.dataGrid = self.grid

            textCell?.commentText = (cellDataObj?.GradingRepair)!

            return true
        }

    return false

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what this code does:

```
    let pickerViewController = GradingController() // 1
    pickerViewController.pickerDelegate = self // 2
    // 3
```

1. You create a completely new GradingController.
2. You assign the GradingController a `pickerDelegate`.
3. Nothing. So you throw the GradingController away. Your code thus has no effect on anything.

What you need to do is to assign a `pickerDelegate` to the actual GradingController that's in your interface. But that's not what you did.

Comment: So I have to add this `pickerDelegate = (self as! PickerDelegate)` to my GradingController?

Comment: That makes no sense to me. Seems like you want the `pickerDelegate` to be the `TextCell`, don't you? So at some point you would need to assign a TextCell object as the `pickerDelegate` of an actual existing GradingController — not some _new_ GradingController that you create and throw away.

Comment: Yes I want the pickerDelegate to be the TextCell

Comment: Then make it so.

Comment: Well, _I_ can't tell you. You have not revealed anything about what a TextCell does in the interface. Presumably at some point when a TextCell comes into existence, there is also an existing GradingController and you can hook them together. But you have totally concealed all information having to do with that. So, under the circumstances, only you can write this code. I believe, however, that I have answered the question: I told you exactly what you were doing wrong, which is what you asked.

Comment: I just want to be able to call updateMessage from GradingController to TextCell

Comment: Okay, so at the moment you say `let textCell = cell as? TextCell`, `textCell` is a TextCell and GradingController is `self`, right? So you can say `self.pickerDelegate = textCell`.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.